# How can I move commits from a pull request to another branch?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a repository on GitHub, and mistakenly made the changes to master. I then made a pull request with the changes. Given that I now want to create a new pull request with different changes, how can I best do that without including my changes from the first request in the second one? Is there a way to move the changes I made from master into another, new, branch, without affecting the original pull request?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

1. Create a new branch from master, say `my-new-feature`.
2. Checkout again to master and revert the commit.
3. Push `master` and `my-new-feature` to origin.

Hope this helps.